# Inline images overlap tag formatting by 1px

Tags: bug, tags, design, images

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Long sentence to test what happens when we post any size image over the top of a tag: [image]

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Long sentence to test what happens when we post any size image over the top of a tag: [image]

Image in case this isn't happening on your browser:

[image]

Chrome 41.0.2272.118, Windows 8

Comment: 1 pixel...­­­­­

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yep, an entire pixel...